# Getting session variable in jsp using struts2 iterator tag

Tags: struts2

Hi i am trying to iterate a list from a session in my jsp. 
The list contains complex objects

my code is shown below

```
<s:if test="#session.rideDetails != null">    
    <s:iterator value="#session.rideDetails" status="ride123">
       <s:textfield name='test' value='<s:property value="#ride123.index"/>'></s:textfield>
       <s:textfield name='test1' value='<s:property value="#ride123.route.location.name"/>'></s:textfield>
   </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

But im not getting the expected result, is there any syntax error in the above code?

Comment: can you show the complete code as well what you mean by expected results?

Comment: <s:if test="#session.rideDetails != null">

    
    <s:iterator value="#session.rideDetails" status="ride123">
    
    <s:textfield name='test' value='<s:property value="#ride123.index"/>'></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name='test1' value='<s:property value="#ride123.route"/>'></s:textfield>
    </s:iterator>

                            </s:if>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<s:if test="#session.rideDetails != null">    
    <s:iterator value="#session.rideDetails" status="stat" var="ride">
       <s:property value="#stat.index"/>
       <s:property value="#ride.route.location.name"/>
   </s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

There are two points you should check:

1. Is there is a `rideDetails` in the session?
2. Use the `var` attribute to capture each ride object.

(The `var` attribute isn't necessary, but can help keep things clear.)

Comment: @srinivasgowda dude, this is an answer 5 years ago, describe your question separately, so that we will be able to help you, `its not working` doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested tags inside Struts2 tags so instead of

```
<s:textfield name='test' value='<s:property value="#ride123.index"/>'></s:textfield>
```

use

```
<s:textfield name="test" value="%{#ride123.index}" />
```